# Which color space is most suitable for color transformation and Why?

Tags: image, image-processing, rgb

Can anyone tell me Which color space is most suitable for color transformation and Why?.For eg RGB, HSI etc

Comment: The one that suits the transformation. Your question is really too broad to answer.

Comment: Actually this question was asked in an assignment. Isn't there any generalized answer for this like in terms of computation cost or so?

Comment: If I have to guess, your teacher intention is probably HSI, because in HSI color space the Hue channel is orthogonal to the other channels, and transforming the colors does not affect the saturation and intensity. It's just a guess... it's hard to know the right answer without some context. In general, the conversion from RGB to other color space (like YUV) is a "color transformation" so "most suitable" is undefined. The answer could also be XYZ, because it is used as transition color space, and it can represent the full gamut of human visual system... LAB may also be the correct answer...

Comment: Yeah I also think that HSI is the one since we are only taught RGB and HSI

Comment: But then RGB would be easiest when simulating color blindness.